# How would you redirect a URL with a # in it with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, redirect

Based on the architecture of the backend of the website, I have to use Javascript. I currently have an old URL (www.website.com/hello/#world) and want to direct it to something else. The problem is, when I go into the backend, hello/#world/ doesn't exist. Rather, I believe it pulls in the data from hello/english/world, I also can't create a #world folder in the hello folder as it gives me an error. Where can I put the redirector JavaScript?

I've tried putting redirecting Javascript in the hello/index.html and hello/english/world/index.html but none of this works because of how the pages redirect from one to another.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.location.replace("www.website.com/blue/");
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: #world isn't pointing anywhere. It's a fragment identifier at /hello. ```if (window.location.hash === '#world) { window.location.href = 'https://www.website.com/blue/ }```

Answer (score 0):

You said you believe you know which page is being served when a user accesses `www.website.com/hello/#world`, right? If you add the following code to that page it should redirect the user to the URL you want if the URL ends with `#world`.

```
<script>
  if(window.location.hash === "#world") {
    window.location.replace("www.website.com/blue/");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Since the #world folder doesn't exist in the backend, would this still work?

Comment: Are you able to test it?

Comment: I have and it doesn't work so I'm guessing since the folder doesn't exist that might be problem?